# read longest identifier in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

hi i'm reading a line from a file and i need to get the longest identifier in that, for example in the line

```
MY_Variable = Some_Variable+New_Variable;
```

in the above line i need to get "Some_Variable". I tried with below code,but i'm getting result as

```
Some_Variable+New_Variable
```

I tried with this

```
    if(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', Line_Read)):       ## To check whether line has identifier or not
    if(len(max(Line_Read.split(), key=len))>32):    ## length of the longest string is greater than 32 or not?
        print max(Line_Read.split(), key=len)       ## printing the identifier
```

please help. Thank you

Comment: Does it works fine for "MY_Variable = Some_Variable + New_Variable ;"?

Comment: Can't you use a delimiter for constructing *MY_Variable like:

    MY_Variable = SomeVariable + '|' + New_Variable

Answer (score 4):

A Python identifier can be defined as `[a-zA-Z_]\w*`:

```
max(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z_]\w*', Line_Read), key=len)
```

This returns

```
'Some_Variable'
```

Comment: @user1915934 - what do you mean by "stripping multiple chars from a string"?

Comment: i cant use string.strip('&','$'), since strip() takes only one argument. So is there any other way to remove those characters from the string?

Comment: @user1915934: `'$&$abc$&$'.strip('$&')` returns `'abc'`